# Can I lose "constness" in the return type of an override virtual function?

Tags: c++

The following code compiles and runs, and no warning is emitted by either gcc or clang:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual std::string const& get() = 0;
};

struct Derived: Base {
    virtual std::string& get() override { return m; }
    std::string m;
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.get() = "Hello, World";

    Base& b = d;
    std::cout << b.get() << "\n";
}
```

Is `std::string&` covariant with `std::string const&` then?

Comment: makes sense, since you can simply re-apply the constness for the caller if needed.   Of course you can't just take it back off automatically, so the opposite wouldn't be true.

Comment: @xaxxon: Yes, I was honestly surprised it worked though (never thought about it!)... especially since CLion unfortunately signals an error there. I raised a bug on their tracker for this.

Comment: Interesting, I see it was also fixed in DR1250 to allow for incomplete types: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1250

Comment: @george: Nice find!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Yes**

This is specified in **class.virtual**, in the latest draft (n4606) we see:

> **§10.3 7/** The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the return type of the overridden function
>   or *covariant* with the classes of the functions. If a function `D::f` overrides a function `B::f`, the return types
>   of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria:
>
> - both are pointers to classes, both are lvalue references to classes, or both are rvalue references to classes<sup>111</sup>
> - the class in the return type of `B::f` is the same class as the class in the return type of `D::f`, or is an unambiguous and accessible direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of `D::f`
> - both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of `D::f` has the same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class type in the return type of `B::f`.

Specifically, the last point addresses exactly the case here: it is acceptable for an overriding type to lose the `const` and/or `volatile` qualifiers (it cannot, however, gain them).

---

Note: as mentioned by [@george](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471160/george) above, paragraph 8/ used to prevent this from working with incomplete class types, but this was [since fixed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1250).